# How do I set a value as a parameter inside an object with plain javascript?

Tags: javascript, key-value

Consider

```
a = {apple: "the value of this is ${value}"}
```

I want to call on this such that

```
a = {apple: "the value of this is ${value}"}
console.log(a.apple("16")) => outputs "the value of this is 16"
```

Anyway to do this in javascript?

Answer (score 3):

do you mean as following:

```
const a = { apple: (value) => `the value of this is ${value}` }
```

Comment: Not really I want to actually call on the object

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a setter

```js
const a = {
  _apple: "the value of this is ",
  set apple(value){ 
      this._apple = this._apple + value;
    }
};

a.apple = '16';

console.log(a._apple);
```